# row_id Tag Parameter isn't working in Matrix field

Tags: add-on, matrix

I'm using Matrix, and the `row_id` tag parameter isn't working for me. At the moment I am on relying on the search Tag Parameter.

This doesn't work:

```
{technical_specifications row_id="1"}{spec_value}{/technical_specifications}
```

Whilst this works:

```
{technical_specifications search:spec_label="Width"}{spec_value}{/technical_specifications}
```

[image: Screenshot of field setup in an entry]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check to make sure your code examples are in the correct place in your question? It seems they are flipped.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl, I have corrected my original question - thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Row IDs in Matrix are unique for the whole site, like entry IDs. So there only will ever be one row with a row_id of '1' – the first row you ever created. If you’ve deleted that row, then no row exists with the ID '1' anymore.

If you just want to grab the first row, use `limit="1"` instead, which will limit the output to only the first row.

If you want to grab the second row, you would use `limit="1"` as well as `offset="1"`, etc..

Both of those parameters are documented on http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix/docs/templates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought row ids was in relation to that specific entry. In that case, I will leave it using the search paramter. Is there any Performance difference between your solution and mine? Which is quicker?

Comment: And is there a way to find out the row id for a particular row?

Comment: Well, `limit="1"` is *quicker*, since it translates to a simple `LIMIT 1` in the SQL query, whereas `search:spec_label="Width"` is going to perform a search on an unindexed column (though you can add the index yourself ;). However considering that the Width column may change positions from entry to entry, or might not be there at all (never trust authors!), `search:spec_label` is a better way to go in your case. Change the value to "=Width" so at least it’s not a LIKE search.

Comment: You can get the row_id for a particular row using the `{row_id}` variable within your Matrix tag pair. Useful if you want to pass it to another template, or include it in the URL, etc.. – eventually to be passed into `row_id="{embed:row_id}"` or `row_id="{segment_4}"`.